# Research on signal processing

Tags: discrete-signals

Inspired by the talk ["You and Your Research"](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/YouAndYourResearch.html) by Richard Hamming, I started wondering what are the important research topics on signal processing nowadays. Certainly an extensive list of topics would not be easy to find. I do not know the trending topics, for example, on Circuits and Systems, but I could imagine it for biomedical engineering.

So, in your opinion, what are some interesting research topics nowadays on signal processing? I could start with compressive sensing and tensor models.

Comment: Whatever my PhD is on  :)

Comment: I'm afraid that there's no answer to your question. Who is to judge what is 'most important' (and for whom?)? If you want to know what is 'hot' just check the articles appearing in the IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing. But note that there are also lots of journals on specific topics in Signal Processing (image processing; audio, speech, and language; circuits and systems II; etc.).